# Parallelization of sequence container in ssis

Tags: ssis, etl

I'm developing SSIS package which has sequence container and within sequence container I have 30 containers. It takes a lot of time to execute the package and I am trying to implement parallel processing.

Is there any way we could implement parallel execution for 30 sequence containers?

I have 30 container out of which 1 container runs long. i want to run that 1 container separate and the remaining 29 together at control flow.

Please advice how to do it

Comment: It is based on the number of core your using. I suggest do the following for better performance. Connect 3 sequence containers in a set. 3 X 10 sets your going to have in your container. Please try this and check if it is fine.

Comment: not working for me. it took more time than expected. Thanks for your response @ Gowdhaman008

Comment: I have figured out the issue. one of the sequence containers is loading slow and it is because of extraction of data is slow from oracle source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any tasks that are not preceded by a precedence constraint will run in parallel.

Comment: How to achieve parallelism at control flow. I have 30 container out of which 1 container runs long. i want to run that 1 container separate and the remaining 29  together at control flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have 1 sequence container which will contain 29 and one out side of the container. Then you can draw flow as per your choice